# After updating to Gazebo 1.3 under ROS Groovy I get a .launch file error

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Another question that might be related to [this one](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1125/after-updating-gazebo-to-13-under-groovy-i-get-an/).

I am using ROS Groovy and I updated Gazebo to 1.3 (binary version), under Ubuntu 12.04. When launching an empty world with the following **.launch** file:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>

  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <group if="$(arg use_sim_time)">
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </group>


  <!-- start empty world -->
  <node name="empty_world_server" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find hit_hand)/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

  <!-- start gui -->
  <group if="$(arg gui)">
    <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

I get the following error:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://groovybeetz4:44318/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    empty_world_server (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6184]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 8a994a92-6ace-11e2-b2ca-6cf049e83b7a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6197]
started core service [/rosout]
process[empty_world_server-2]: started with pid [6211]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [6220]
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5e77700 (LWP 6248)]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Msg Waiting for master.[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffdb998700 (LWP 6315)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdb197700 (LWP 6316)]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
  what():  Character [-] at element [20] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [empty_world_server13-01-30].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff54b1425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Did the launch file semantics change, or it is related to the other error?

Thanks, Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1126/after-updating-to-gazebo-1.3-under-ros-groovy-i-get-a-.launch-file-error/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out, in the launch file the node name is not allowed anymore to have the "_" character in the name.

```
<!-- start empty world -->
  <node name="empty_world_server" .. />
```

becomes:

```
<!-- start empty world -->
  <node name="emptyworldserver" .. />
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/866/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-09**:
I'm almost positive that's not true.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-07-10**:
this must have been a bug at the moment: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException' what():  Character [-] at element [20] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [empty_world_server13-01-30].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.` event though the `_` is listed.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/866/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-24**:
Yeah that's referring to a graphics resource name, not a node name. But I think I've recently discovered the source of that error: it's a bug in Gazebo 1.5 on 32-bit machines.